# Working With Database Results in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am an RoR noob.  I am selecting all records from a model and saving it into a variable, but am having difficulty determining how to grab a specific field.

For example, I have a model called Stats that maps to a stats view in a MySQL database. The view has the following columns: `pet, height, weight`.

This is how I am grabbing the data:  `@dog_distribution = Distribution.where(pet: 'dog')`.

Assume that 3 records are returned, how can I grab the weight value of the first record?

Answer (score 1):

To view all weight values, you may try something like this

```
@dog_distribution = Distribution.where(pet: 'dog').pluck(:weight)
```

This will return array with weight of each element.

If you need value of only first element, try something like this

```
@dog_distribution = Distribution.where(pet: 'dog').first.weight
```

Comment: What if I want to grab more than just the value for the height columns? What if I had 10 records and only wanted the third one.  I am coming from a PHP background, where can assign the results of a database query as an array.  So in PHP the equivalent would be something like $stats_r = [database result] I can do something like this:  $stats_r[2]['height'], $stats_r[4]['weight'], etc...  It seems like the above solution forces me to create a variable for every record/column, but I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: @BadProgrammer [.where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns you array of active records. If you want to access third element you can easily do it using `@dog_distribution = Distribution.where(pet: 'dog')[3].weight` It will return third element's weight

Comment: Don't use `.where(pet: 'dog').first`, use `.find_by(pet: 'dog')` instead.

Comment: You can use `offset` too: `.where(pet: 'dog').offset(2).take.weight`